# Why is show 0001 not returning "0001"?

Tags: haskell

I am just asking a quick simple question here.  I'm trying to code poker card rankings into 4 digit binary code (exp. 2 is 0010, 7 is 0111)(ignoring the suits for now).  Then decoding and print it out.

To my knowledge the best way of changing a Int into a String is by using the function show.  However, using it on this situation it drops all the zeros that is in front of the 1 (exp. show 0011 returns "11", show 0001 returns "1").  How do I keep the zeros?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 0001 is a number, and not a character string. The 0001 read syntax is converted into an integer object, and when you print that integer object, it prints in decimal as 1.

1 is the successor to 0. There are no zeros in 1. :)

To print 1 as 0001, try the prelude that provides printf:

E.g

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html

Answer (score 3):

To me it seems like you are converting it into integers rather than bytes
integers are real numbers, so the zeros are removed.

to keep the zeros you have to keep the data as a string or create an array of bytes, if its converted into an integer the zeros are droped.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a custom Int->String conversion function that pads the string to the appropriate number of digits, e.g. if you always want 4 digits, `1` would show as `0001` and `32` would show as `0032`. [`Text.Printf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Text-Printf.html) is probably the right tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

0011 is not the binary representation for 3, it's the decimal number for eleven padded with some zeros. Since I don't see any reason to represent cards with binary number apart from doing some bit operation, you should be careful of that error.

If you really want to work with binary representation of your number, you should write a conversion function :

```
stringToBin :: String -> Int    
stringToBin xs 
  | all (`elem` "01") xs = foldl' (\acc b -> 2 * acc + digitToInt b) 0 xs
  | otherwise = error (xs ++ " is not a binary string")

bin = stringToBin
sample = bin"0011"
check = sample == 3
```

And to present them, another function, with printf to pad the result and unfoldr and reverse to generate the list of digits.

But are you sure that you want to use this encoding ? A more symbolic approach is usually easier to use.

```
data Card = Card Value Suit deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
data Value = N Int | J | Q | K | A deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
data Suit = ...
```

---

EDIT : I forgot that the Numeric module (comes with GHC) has a showIntAtBase function and a readInt :

```
stringToBin = fst . head . readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt
binToString n = showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit n ""
```

Though it still won't do the padding for you.

Comment: Thanks for your post, you may be right to say it's not a good way of representing cards.  I was just exploring ways to do it.  And I found this issue interesting, and wanted to understand it more.
Thanks for everyone that had input I will give it all a go.